# NodeJS crypto Module - didn't get an encrypted string

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to implement nodejs crypto module in typescript, here is my code

```
 const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'a secret', {});
```

But the variable hmac is not an ecrypted string. it is an object, please see the attached screenshot, in need to write the encrypted string in console, how can i get the string ?

[image]

Comment: I don't think this what you want.
https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhmac_algorithm_key_options

Comment: i'm using "crypto.createHmac", but  the result i got is not an encrypted string, its an object like the screenshot, how to extract the encrypted string from this object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'a secret');
hmac.update('some data to hash');
console.log(hmac.digest('hex')); //"hex" | "base64" | "latin1"
```

[Documentation for the above methods](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hmac_digest_encoding)